# D3 on Angular: How to use d3-plugins in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm already using d3 in my angular app like it is described in this [BLOG POST](http://www.robinwieruch.de/?p=6). However I want to use a [D3-PLUGIN](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins) called fisheye in my application. I already installed it with bower including the dependency:

```
"d3-plugins-fisheye": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-plugins/master/fisheye/fisheye.js"
```

After that I included the file in my index.html. The loading works fine.

```
<script src="bower_components/d3-plugins-fisheye/index.js"></script>
```

However I can't use `var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular().radius(120);` in my d3 directive. D3 is working fine. I already tried to load the additional plugin via a service:

```
angular.module('fisheye', [])
  .factory('fisheyeService', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope', function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
  var d = $q.defer();
  function onScriptLoad() {
    // Load client in the browser
    $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.fisheye); });
  }
  // Create a script tag with fisheye as the source
  // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
  // has been loaded
  var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  scriptTag.async = true;
  scriptTag.src = 'bower_components/d3-plugins-fisheye/index.js';
  scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 'complete') { onScriptLoad(); }
  };
  scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

  var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  s.appendChild(scriptTag);

  return {
    fisheye: function() { return d.promise; }
  };
}]);
```

And use it in my d3 directive with:

```
d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
  fisheyeService.fisheye().then(function(fisheye) {

    ...

    var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular().radius(120);
    //var fisheye = fisheye.circular().radius(120);

    ...

  });
});
```

But it is still not working. Does anyone know how to load a additional d3-plugin in my directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it by using the fisheyeService from my question at my directive like this:

```
fisheyeService.fisheye().then(function() {
  var fisheyePlugin = d3.fisheye;
  d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
    d3.fisheye = fisheyePlugin;

    ...

    var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular().radius(120);

    ...
```

You can use [this BLOG POST](http://www.robinwieruch.de/?p=177) for further instructions.